# Meaning of $\psi$ in regard to $p$-value distributions

Tags: p-value, notation

In [Combining dependent P-values by Kost & McDermott](http://www.sciencedirect.com.proxy.bib.uottawa.ca/science/article/pii/S0167715202003103), the notation $\psi$ is used in a way that I am not familiar with. Relevant passge:

> 2.1. *Known Variance*. 
>   Let $(X_1,…,X_{k0})′∼N_{k0}(μ,Σ)$, where $Σ$ is a known nonsingular covariance matrix. Suppose it is of interest to test $H_0:\mu_i=\mu_{i0}$ for all $i$ versus the alternative $H_1:\mu_i<\mu_{i0}$ for at least one $i$, where the $μ_{i0} (i=1,…,k_0)$ are known constants. If the p-values $P_i=Φ((Xi−μi0)/σi), i=1,…,k_0$, are independent, $\psi_F=-2\sum logP_i \sim X^2_{2k_0}$ under $H_0$. In this case, where the $P_i$ are dependent, Brown (1975) suggested approximating the distribution of $Ψ_F$ with that of a scaled $χ^2$ random variable. The scale factor and degrees of freedom are chosen so that the exact and approximate distributions have identical first and second moments. The mean and variance of $Ψ_F$ are 
>   $E[\psi_F]=2k_0$ and $var(\psi_F)=4k_0+2\sum cov(-2logP_i,-2logP_j)$

In this example, does $\psi_F$ refer to the null distribution of $p$-values? Specifically, the null distribution of $p$-values for an $F$ distribution? $\psi_T$, $\psi_F$, and $\psi_N$ are all referenced at some point.  The cited publication (Brown 1975) does not use this notation.

I just wanted to check this before moving on.